Craft 4.8.0 : Hide some entries to a group of user
I have somes entries :

POI-1
POI-2
POI-3

I have two groups of users :

Group-1
Group-2

Needs :

The Group-1 can edit only POI-1
The Group-2 can edit only POI-2 and POI-3

I see that I can set this kinds of conditions only to Tabs and Fields.
I tried on Tabs like this but not working :

I should see at least Tab of POI-1 with user from Group-1. I got this results for all entries when trying to edit it :

Am I doing something wrong ?

The "Current User Condition" evaluates attributes on the current user editing the entry – so having Slug equals poi-1 in there isn't right as the slug to evaluate is on the entry, not the user.
To fix that, you need to delete the Slug equals poi-1 rule from the "Current User Condition", and create it below the "Entry Condition" section instead.

Not sure if you can hide the entry in the CP just based on the user group... likely you'll have to separate those entries em distinct sections to do so.
Another approach, would be allow them to see then entry, but not make changes using EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE and a field to store the groups allowed to edit i.e. userGroup
Event::on(
    Entry::class,
    Element::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE,
    static function(ModelEvent $event) {
        /** @var Entry $entry */
        $entry = $event->sender;

        $groups = $user = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity()->getGroups();

        if (!in_array($entry->userGroup, $groups)) {
            $entry->addError('userGroup', 'Not allowed...');
            $event->isValid = false;
        }
    }
);

